# How to remove space before Range Slider in JQ Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, range

I am using JQMobile Range Slider. I wish to remove the input box that I was able to get rid off using ui-hidden-accessible class. However it doesn't remove the space before the slider which looks odd. Please advise how can I remove the leading space on the left.

Here is the HTML for both:

```
<form class="full-width-slider">
    <input type="range" data-mini="true" name="TimePage" id="TimePage" data-highlight="true" min="0" max="100"  value="50" onchange="DisplaySliderTime()">
</form>                    


<form class="full-width-slider">
    <input type="range" class="ui-hidden-accessible" data-mini="true" name="TimePage" id="TimePage" data-highlight="true" min="0" max="100"  value="50" onchange="DisplaySliderTime()">
</form>
```

And this is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EWQ6n/492)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to modify or override this CSS to suit:

```
.ui-slider-track, .ui-slider-switch {
     margin: 0 15px 0 68px;
}
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/EWQ6n/493

Comment: What if I need to apply this on one of the sliders (the second one) and keep the other slider as it is?

Comment: Take a gander at the basics of CSS selection. You can target individual forms a number of ways. Put IDs on your forms, or use the index of the form with :nth-child().